# C# Заменить повторяющиеся слова их количеством

Tags: c#

Есть текст -

```
cat cat cat cat cat cat cat cat cat cat dog dog dog dog dog
```

Я делаю из текста массив строк с помощью `Text.Split(' ')`. Как потом пользуясь циклом foreach получить такой текст? -

```
cat_10 dog_5
```

Если слово встречается один раз подряд - нужно делать `cat_1`

Comment: а если текст в одном экземпляре?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ поправил

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ну, можно попробовать так:

```
string text = "cat cat cat cat cat cat cat cat cat cat dog dog dog dog dog";
var result = text.Split().GroupBy(x => x).Select(group=> $"{group.Key}_{group.Count()}");
var resultString = string.Join(" ", result);
```

1. Разбиваем через Split.
2. Группируем по значению.
3. Преобразуем в коллекцию `IEnumerable<string>`, где каждое значение будет вида `Key_count`.
4. С помощью `string.Join` преобразуем коллекцию в строку.
   * Этот пункт можно вовсе заменить, путем добавления после `select()` что то вроде `.Aggregate((current, next) => current + " " + next)`. Тогда вы сразу будете получать нужную вам строку.

Если вам по какой либо причине не хочется использовать LINQ и все новые навороты C#, то делайте тогда что то по типу следующего:

```
string text = "cat cat cat cat cat cat cat cat cat cat dog dog dog dog dog";
string[] arr = text.Split();
string result = "";
foreach (var val in arr)
{
    if (!result.Contains(val))
    {
        int count = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i] == val)
                count++;
        }
        result += val + "_" + count + " ";
    }
}
```

Для скорости можно использовать `StringBuilder`, а все циклы на `for`.

Результат:

```
cat_10 dog_5
```

Answer (score 2):

При помощи регулярки:

```
string text = "wolf cat cat cat cat cat cat cat cat cat cat dog dog dog dog dog";
Regex r = new Regex(@"((\w+)( \2)*)");
string result = r.Replace(text, m => m.Groups[2].Value + "_" + m.Value.Split().Length);
```

Результат:

```
wolf_1 cat_10 dog_5
```