# Подсчет количества вхождений каждого из символов в строке

Tags: c#

Нужно написать алгоритм который подсчитает сколько элементов одного вида в строке. Начал делать, попал в тупик:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
namespace Reverse_String
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            
            string a = Console.ReadLine();
            var str = Regex.Replace(a, "[-.?!) ;(,:]", "").ToLower();
            char[] ch = new char[str.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
            {
                ch[i] = str[i];
            }
            
            for (int i = 0;i < ch.Length; i++)
            {
                int k = 0;
                for(int j = 0; j < ch.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (ch[i] == ch[j])
                    {
                        k++;
                        Console.WriteLine($"{ch[i]}  {k}");
                        
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Пример: Корова к-1, о-2, р-1, в-1 , а-1.
Подскажите Пожалуйста, что делаю не так, где ошибся.

Comment: Помню был [такой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/840423/220553), для букв аналогично, только разбивать не надо.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Подставил, что-то не получилось или я чего-то не понял. Не могли бы объяснить? Или написать как это должно выглядеть. Пожалуйста.

Comment: Вы это сейчас серьезно? В том ответе от меня подробнейшее объяснение, ну и тут я вам сказал "только разбивать не надо". Убрали `.Split()`, написали нужное слово, получили нужный [результат](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mQWrGU). Плохо, когда не хочется думать...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Тысяча благодарностей. Всё, догнал. Спасибо

Comment: @EvgeniyZ закроем как дубль?

Comment: @tym32167 Ну у вас дубина есть, конечно закрывайте)